# I want to connect to remote Mysql Database from Java

Tags: java, mysql, remote-server

I want to connect my application running on Java and MySQL to a remote server which has Mysql database in it and want to do update when the local database is updated. What is the current and popular technology available to do this (technology in the sense i refer to things like hibernate,jni, jdbc etc..)

How do I sync to remote server when some update happens in the local machine ? I know this is possible but I need a start..

Comment: in other words "give me teh codez" not so much ... show what you have attempted and where it is not working and ask a specific question

Comment: i am not asking about code here. i just want to know some techniques on how to do this. fo example for normal DB operations we use JDBC so similarly for remote server what should i do ? if the question is not clear please ask me. dont close this. i want this to be reopend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysql's *replication* feature